# jquery submit is not working from $.post callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit

I have jQuery code like this.

```js
$("#continue").click(function () {
  var policy = { policy: context.model, returnUrl : context.returnUrl };
  $.post(context.continueUrl, ko.toJS(policy))
  .done(function(data) {
    if (data.response === "success") {
      if (context.continueType === "POST") {
        $("#redirect").submit();
      }
      window.location.href = context.returnUrl;
    } else {
      window.location.href = context.errorUrl;
    }
  });
});
```

Problem is that `$("#redirect").submit();` Should send a form using `POST`. But send it as `GET` method. If I call this from console it works fine.

form:

```
<form id="redirect" action="MYURL" method="post" style="display: none;">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
</form>
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: $("#redirect")[0].submit(); did you try this?

Comment: yes I did. Didn't work :(

Comment: post and redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I was just being completely stupid.
it should be.

```
if (context.continueType === "POST") {
    document.getElementById("redirect").submit();
} else { //This else was missing so it did redirect instead
    window.location.href = context.returnUrl;
}
```